# pdfbox2 writing text does not apply text in reading order

Tags: pdfbox

Im writing text to a tagged PDF (Accessible) using showText function.
The text I have added is displayed, visually, in the correct position. However when reading the document with screen reader, the text is been read at the end and not according to the visual order.
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: *"Im writing text to a tagged PDF (Accessible) using showText function."* - The _showText_ function alone does not create tagging or guarantee accessibility. Thus, either you base your code on mistaken assumptions, or you do something in addition to using _showText_ to ensure accessibility and don't tell us about that.